# How to call button click delegate of one ascx on another ascx button click?

Tags: c#, asp.net, delegates

I have a ascx page suppose page1.ascx in that I have a button click event handler

```
btnSave.Click +=
      delegate
            {
                if (Save != null) Save(this, EventArgs.Empty);                   

            };
```

and I have another ascx page suppose page2.ascx in that I have a button click

```
protected void btnEdit_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  // want to call 
   btnSave.Click +=delegate
                 {
                if (Save != null) Save(this, EventArgs.Empty);                   

            };
}
```

I want to call btnSave click delegate(page1.ascx) on btnEdit(page2.ascx). Is it possible if yes then how?

Comment: You don't want to trigger an event but to call a method. So implement a public method `Save` in second UserControl and call it from `page1`.

Answer (score 1):

If I understood what you mean, one way would be as below:

```
public class Control1 : UserControl {
   public delegate void ButtonClickHandler(object sender, EventArgs e);

   public ButtonClickHandler ButtonClickEvent {get;set;}

   public void Save(object sender, EventArgs e) {
      //do something
      if (ButtonClickEvent != null) {ButtonClickEvent(sender, e);}
      //do something
   }
}

public class Control2 : UserControl {
   protected override void OnLoad(EventArgs e) {
      control1.ButtonClickEvent += YourMethod;
   }

   protected void YourMethod(object sender, EventArgs e) { // do something here ... }
}
```

Another way is to declare your button's event in the first control as property and assign your method in the 2nd control.

Answer (score 0):

I'd recommend moving the code out of the code-behind and into a separate class, so that it is accessible to both .ascx files.